# Conditional bit setting

Tags: c, security, optimization, conditional-statements

From my small research, the two functions below are equivalent (from performance point of view) because even very light optimization (`-O1`) results in the identical assembly code.

Code 1:

```
#define BIT_N (10)

extern unsigned int isBitSet;

unsigned int Foo() {
    unsigned int res1 = 0;

    if (isBitSet)
    {
        res1 |= ( 1u << BIT_N );
    }

    return res1;
}
```

Code 2:

```
#define BIT_N (10)

extern unsigned int isBitSet;

unsigned int Foo() {
    unsigned int res1 = 0;

    res1 |= ( (!!isBitSet) << BIT_N );

    return res1;
}
```

The disassembly is identical for *Code 1* and *Code 2* (after compilation with gcc 6.3 for x86_64 +optimization `-O2`):

```
Foo():
    mov     edx, DWORD PTR isBitSet[rip]
    xor     eax, eax
    test    edx, edx
    setne   al
    sal     eax, 10
    ret
```

I personally prefer the C version of *Code 2*, it looks cleaner to me. But is it as safe as *Code 1*? Because I see some potential pitfalls like if `isBitSet` were of type `int` and `BIT_N` 31, that code `res1 = ( (!!isBitSet) << BIT_N);` would lead to *undefined behavior*.

**Question(s):**

Are there any additional pitfalls? Is *Code 1* really safer than *Code 2*?
If yes, is there any known ways to make the *Code 2* safer without too much overhead?

Comment: what if `res1 = 5` on the start?

Comment: @tilz0R then that code `res1 = ( (!!isBitSet) << BIT_N );` would be `res1 |= ( (!!isBitSet) << BIT_N );` but again, the disassembly would be the same.

Comment: "The disassembly is identical for Code 1 and Code 2". If it is, your compiler is broken. Code 1 uses `|=`  and code 2 uses `=`.

Comment: @AlexLop: Let's assume `isBitSet` variable is not false. First example `res1 = 5` will after checking `if` statement set bits: `res1 = 0x...0100 0000 0101`. In second example, this won't be the case anymore.

Comment: @JeremyP but it doesn't change the result. +See my comment to **tilz0R**

Comment: @JeremyP I modified the code to have the identical `|=`. But that's really not the point here.

Comment: On your first comment, this is not true. Assigning or OR operation can't be the same. @AlexLop. This is now ok for both approaches.

Comment: So, OK, if we know all agree on the code in question, let's clean up the comments. I'll go first.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Hmm, I read it wrong. I assumed `res1` was some kind of parameter without really looking at where it came from because why would you bother otherwise?

Comment: My opinion is that code 1 is better because it looks cleaner and it is more obvious what it is doing.

Comment: I find `if (isBitSet)` to be extremely much clearer than `(!!isBitSet)`. You should consider making it easy for people reading the code much more than for the compiler (which seems to get it anyway).

Comment: @BoPersson Assume you have `N` variables which indicate if bit `n` should be `0` or `1`. Instead of `N` if statements to set each bit you combine one expression `X = ((!!N0) | ((!!N1) << 1) |...| ((!!Nn) << n) );`

Comment: @Alex - Just saying that in Code 1 it is immediately clear to me what happens. In Code 2 I have to stop and think about it. And that's where bugs are hiding. I might also do `if (isBitSet) return 1u << BIT_N; else return 0;` and find *that* clearer.

Answer (score 2):

> Because I see some potential pitfalls like if isBitSet were of type int and BIT_N 31

You've already gone through another pitfall right there, namely that you assume that the type of `isBitSet` matters. All "logical" operators in C such as `!` returns type `int` with value 1 or 0.

So the expression `(!!isBitSet) << BIT_N` is per design dangerous and should not be used, because of the mentioned undefined behavior.

Another reason why it shouldn't be used is because the programmer might incorrectly believe that the resulting type of the expression is the type of `isBitSet`. So if the programmer would write something that for example relies on unsigned wrap-around, like this:

```
((!!isBitSet) << BIT_N) + UINT16_C(something)
```

then that would also cause undefined behavior = integer overflow on a 32 bit system, since the left operand of `+` is signed, which wasn't intended.

The root of the problem is using multiple operators on a single line. This is almost always bad practice and can lead to numerous bugs. My experience is also that the presence of the `!!` trick is often a sign of fishy code.

The ideal, fully portable version of your code would be:

```
uint32_t Foo (void) 
{ 
  uint32_t result;

  if(isBitSet)
  {
    result = 1u << BIT_N;
  }
  else
  {
    result = 0;
  }

  return result;
}
```

Or if you will, fully equivalent:

```
uint32_t Foo (void) 
{ 
  return isBitSet ? 1u<<BIT_N : 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Type returned by the operator `!` is `int`, so it's possible to get UB. (Signedness of `isBitSet` type doesn't matter).

From N1570, 6.5.7 Bitwise shift operators:

> 4. The result of `E1 << E2` is E1 left-shifted E2 bit positions; vacated bits are filled with
>      zeros. If E1 has an unsigned type, the value of the result is E1 × 2<sup>E2</sup>, reduced modulo
>      one more than the maximum value representable in the result type. **If E1 has a signed
>      type and nonnegative value, and E1 × 2<sup>E2</sup> is representable in the result type, then that is
>      the resulting value; otherwise, the behavior is undefined.**

However, fix is straight forward; cast to unsigned type before shift:

```
res1 |= (unsigned)(!!isBitSet) << BIT_N;
```

There should not be any overhead on 2's completement machine, so cast is essentially free.

Comment: The type of `isBitSet` does not matter.

Answer (score 0):

The [type of `!!isBitSet` is `int`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_logical) (with a value of either `0` or `1`). The subsequent [left-shift results in undefined behavior if the resulting value cannot be represented as an `int`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_arithmetic). For example, assuming a 32 bit `int` and two's complement, this will happen if `!!isBitSet == 1` and `BIT_N >= 31` (because then the 1 bit is shifted into or beyond the sign bit). So, the potential pitfall you mentioned is indeed one.

Other than that, the code is well defined, and both functions have the same behavior. So, as long as you avoid the conditions for the undefined behavior mentioned above, the second function is equivalent to the first.

That said, the first should probably be preferred, since it's more explicit about its intent (and hence easier to read), and has no chance of undefined behavior.